# Tab bar not visible on Tab Bar Controller on reverse Segue operation

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, segue, swift4

So, I am still in a learning phase of iOS programming using Swift and got stuck in one issue.

I have a Tab bar controller with options in the tab bar at the bottom.
In one of the tab pages, I have table cells, on click of each, I move the user to a WebView (Embedded in a UIViewController).

On the webView I have placed a back button, which is linked to the main Tab Bar Controller through a segue.

I am able to come back to tab bar controller successfully, but after coming back the tab bar at the bottom does not show.

Also, how can I remove the "

I have attached the main.storyboard screenshot for reference.[Main Storyboard flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnY8Q.png)

Comment: connect the unwind segue to tableview page and not to tabbarcontroller

Comment: @Vinodh I tried that as well, but still no luck.

Comment: post it as as answer so others will know

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using the Segue type as "Show Detail" instead of just "Show".